# sybase: fail to drop default of a column

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

We want to change a column type from smallint to decimal. The 'alter table' sql statement passed in a UAT db server but failed in a production server. DBA suggests it could  be related to the 'default' constraint of the column but that is all the help we got.

I am thinking of dropping the default off first before altering the column type.

I tried this sql statement:

```
alter table MyTable alter MyColumn drop default
```

But I got this error message:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'alter'.

SQLState:  ZZZZZ
ErrorCode: 156
```

What is wrong with this syntax? The target DB is 15.5

I used [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/BABCGFHG.htm) as syntax reference

Comment: You are referencing Sybase IQ documents, but I don't recall a 15.5 version of IQ.  Can you confirm that it's IQ, and not ASE or SQLAnywhere?

Comment: It is not Sybase IQ. Sorry, sybase documentation has always been rather confusing to me. I probably have looked up the wrong source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you may be using Sybase ASE, given the version number you listed, and the fact that the Sybase IQ syntax gave you an error message.

For SAP Sybase ASE you would drop the default using the `sp_unbindefault` command.

```
sp_unbindefault 'MyTable.MyColumn'
```

Documentation:
[Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5 > Reference Manual: Procedures > System Procedures](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/X87638.htm)